# How to perform element-wise multiplication of two vectors having different dimensions

Tags: tensorflow

I have two vectors A & B having dimensions (1, 100) & (784, 100) respectively. I thought A would be broadcast along the raw to the same dimension as B, but got error that "Dimensions must be equal". Can you please explain why?

Comment: Would you mind post the code that got error? Tensorflow should handle the broadcasting issue internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadcasting of matrices with the same rank (i.e. `2`) seems to work as [it says on the tin](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
# 1.3.0

A = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], dtype=tf.float32)
B = tf.constant([[1, -1]], dtype=tf.float32)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(A * B)
# array([[ 1., -2.],
#        [ 3., -4.],
#        [ 5., -6.]], dtype=float32)

sess.run(tf.multiply(A, B))
# array([[ 1., -2.],
#        [ 3., -4.],
#        [ 5., -6.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thank you very much